# iOS dependency Injection frameworks (best practices)

Tags: c#, ios, objective-c, dependency-injection, caliburn.micro

I recently got into an iOS team where the test coverage is really bad (12%). The reason being that there is no code isolation and mocking is hard as bulk of the code related to UI lies in the controller and they are not separated out into different classes.

I am trying to get a dependency injection framework setup into this project with a forethought of getting the code coverage up.

Questions, 
Consider I choose one of the dependency injection frameworks like Typhoon or Blood Magic or anything else available out there. Will I be able to do it part by part? Like one ViewController a time. Any tips on this? Or any framework that helps make this happen?  This project is a big project with about 150,000 lines of code.

Any help appreciated. I am a total noob in iOS but I understand the concepts of dependency injection as I have heavily used it in Windows app development.

Answer (score 1):

Hi @golldy and welcome to iOS development!

It seems I'm your exact opposite when it comes to experiences: I've got a lot of iOS development experience but just read about dependency injection and I'm therefore new to it in some way. ;)

Although there seems to be even a [Swift solution for dependency injection](https://github.com/Swinject/Swinject) and without making any valuations about dependency injection in iOS I want to **point out that there are many ways to decouple responsibilities from your controllers** in iOS.

I do agree on the criticism on heavy loaded and not very testable view controllers in iOS. But I prefer solutions like the [**Coordinator** suggestion by Khanlou](http://khanlou.com/2015/10/coordinators-redux/). Maybe you want to take a look?

Good luck with your tests!

***P.S.:***
Note that [Quick](https://github.com/Quick/Quick) is a popular and recommendable **framework for writing tests** (improved readability and more [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) code).

Answer (score 0):

Before adding frameworks consider to use standard toolchain that already exists in Xcode. Xcode use interface builder for construct interfaces and prototype object graph, that could be unarchived at runtime. For inject some dependency simply add object (NSObject) in your xib (or storyboard), fill Class property in inspector, and make outlet connections. NSObject has some methods that you can use for controlling unarciving process: -awakeFromNib, -awakeAfterUsingCoder: and so on.

More about nib files you can find here https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/LoadingResources/CocoaNibs/CocoaNibs.html look The Object Loading Process section